django runserver suddenly gives error "double free detected in tcache 2"
I have a django app which suddenly started giving me this error. I have not made changes to the code in the app, and the app runs fine on other servers. So it must be some configuration on my computer. But I have absolutely no idea how to troubleshoot it, and I cannot find any relevant answers when googling the error. Help?
$ python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
free(): double free detected in tcache 2

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04. Django 4.1.4.

That is a C++ exception. Did you upgrade to another Django version or Python version? If so, what were the previous versions for both and what is the new version?

I didn't perform any upgrades recently. I'm running python 3.8.18 / django 4.1.4. I have access to a couple of other servers where I do NOT have this issue. They run python 3.8.16 / django 4.1.0. But again, it hasn't changed lately.

and I  just tried to revert to django 4.1.0, just in case, to match the servers where it is working ok. But I have the same issue.

1- Isolate the Environment:
Use a virtual environment to isolate dependencies and avoid conflicts with system packages.
2 - Run Under Debugger:
Running your Django app under a debugger like "gdb" can provide more insights into where the error occurs.
gdb --args python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000
# Then type 'run' in the gdb prompt

I hope it helps you to fix your problem.
